# How local host is shared to Internet?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, localhost, tunnel, ssh-tunnel

Recently I have found websites which generate a public URL for a given local host. I'm immensely interested in understanding how a local host can be shared to Internet.

After searching a lot I got to know that it deals with something called 'SSH Tunneling' and 'Port forwarding'. I don't know much about Networking but would like to know more about how a public URL of a local host can be generated.

Can someone explain me how this process goes on? Or can point me to the links which can help me to understand the whole process.

Comment: Do you mean that if you host a local webserver how this could be made available for other in a public way?

Comment: Yeah! @IvanViktorovic

Comment: I would **strongly** suggest you get to know much about networking before proceeding. Doing what you require is impossible without a thorough understanding of networking - it requires either learning how to control everybody's home router, or providing your own network of servers to proxy everybody's home website, including VPN, DHCP, and DNS infrastructure.

Answer (score 3):

First of all if your computer is connectet to the internet it has some kind of public ip address (or at least you rounter and not your computer).

This address is e.g 123.123.123.123. Depending on your ISP this address might change every time you disconnect and reconnect to the internet. Other computers on the internet can reach your Network or pc using this ip 123.123.123.123.

Now if you want to make a local webserver avaiable to the internet you need to set up your router (or pc) to allow external users to access your computer using port 80 (HTTP protocol) or port 443 (https protocol).

As soon you defined such rules other will be able to access the webseite using your public ip 123.123.123.123 .

Now of cause no one likes to remember ip adresses like 123.123.123.123 and thats why there is a system called DNS(Domain Name Service). This service allows you to connect addresses like 123.123.123.123 to a name like mywebsite.de. So if someone types www.mywebsite.de the DNS system will resolve that to 123.123.123.123 witch points to your pc.

I hope this is somehow a start.

Comment: Thanks @Ivan. I got the overview of how it works. But how do I allow external users to access my computer? If they access my PC via HTTP, how can they see the site I'm running on a particular localhost? Can you point me to some links which can help me get deeper into this?

Comment: You allow users via router or firewall rules to access your computer. Depending on the ports you allow the could use differnt services. If you run a webserver on you computer this server will listen to port 80 (or the port you set your pc to listen to) if there are any requests and answer this requests.

Comment: your idea is valid if he has a public IP, but as I see he doesn't own a public IP

Comment: If he doesent have a public IP he could use dynamic DNS services. Then hee needs to install a client on his PC then it communicates the ip erverytime it changes

Answer (score 2):

If you create an SSH Tunnel you create a secure tunnel to the remote computer on your local network (like a VPN but only to a single computer/device) - thus if you browse to your server IP (a LAN IP) it'll work as if you were within your LAN (i.e. at home or at your business).

Port forwarding is different as this tells your modem/router to open (and direct ("forward")) external requests to your public IP to the server device you choose within your LAN.

I believe port forwarding is what you're mainly referring to because you can, in theory, open your "localhost" to the Internet. Technically it's not "localhost" but your web server listening on more IPs (your LAN IP) than just "localhost"...

You will still need to port forward to enable SSH to work.

Comment: Thankyou! But I didn't understand it clearly. The Tunneling part.  Can you please explain it in a broader way? :)

Comment: Tunneling means that you tunnel connection from a point A to a point B. For example you want to connect to the MySQL database on a server `80.100.120.1`, but it only accepts connections from `localhost` port `3306`. Then you first create a SSH tunnel from you computer to the server `80.100.120.1`. Lets say you want that when you connect to `locahost:3306` it will connect to `80.100.120.1:3306`, then you create tunnel with following command:
`ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 80.100.120.1 -N`
after that you can connect to the MySQL server through your computer.

Answer (score 0):

To correctly answer we would need to have the addresses of the web sites you are talking about to check how they work.

A possible way could be that :

- you install a program provided by the web site on your computer
- this program connect to the provider server and establish a tunnel
- once the tunnel is established, the provider has a way to access the computer ressources.
- the provider create a dns record like "customer17.providername.com "for your computer. That record point to the provider server
- when somebody try to connect to your computer, they use the name customer17.providername.com, they are dirrected to the provider server which in turn send the request to your computer trough the tunnel.

It's the way Teamviewer works (altough not with a DNS record but with an internal ID)